# Library housing CNN shape calculation in a function?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I find myself continually re-implementing the same free function for a convolutional neural network's output shape, given hyperparameters.  I am growing tired of re-implementing this function and occasionally also unit tests.

> [image: pytorch nn.Conv3d shape formulae]

[source](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv3d.html)

Is there a library (preference to `pytorch`, `tensorflow`, or `numpy`) that houses a function that implements this formula?

---

Here is what I just implemented for a PyTorch-based project using Python 3.10+, but I would rather just import this.

```py
def conv_conversion(
    in_shape: tuple[int, ...],
    kernel_size: int | tuple[int, ...],
    padding: int | tuple[int, ...] = 0,
    dilation: int | tuple[int, ...] = 1,
    stride: int | tuple[int, ...] = 1,
) -> tuple[int, ...]:
    """Perform a Conv layer calculation matching nn.Conv's defaults."""

    def to_tuple(value: int | tuple[int, ...]) -> tuple[int, ...]:
        return (value,) * len(in_shape) if isinstance(value, int) else value

    k, p = to_tuple(kernel_size), to_tuple(padding)
    dil, s = to_tuple(dilation), to_tuple(stride)
    return tuple(
        int((in_shape[i] + 2 * p[i] - dil[i] * (k[i] - 1) - 1) / s[i] + 1)
        for i in range(len(in_shape))
    )
```

Comment: Why don't you use that `CONV3D` provided by pytorch?

Comment: I am asking for a function that handles a formula, not a layer I can use in a model

Comment: Your question is clear, but what is wrong with your implementation? There is no built-in function in any library which compute these 3 formulas.

Comment: Oh my implementation works, I was more hoping it was an implementation I don't have to repeatedly re-create, and could instead just `import`

Comment: @IntrastellarExplorer Are you looking for something like this https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv3d?  (operate same as method and layer).

Comment: Thank you @Innat!  That computes a conv given an input tensor, which is basically like a conv layer.  I am looking for conv output shape calculations here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is such a function in keras, namely [`conv_output_length`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/e6784e4302c7b8cd116b74a784f4b78d60e83c26/keras/utils/conv_utils.py#L118) that computes the size of the dimension given a specific kernel size, dilation rate and strides.

The only downside is that it supports only 3 types of padding: None ("valid"), padding the input such as the output has the same spatial dimensions as the input ("same"), or to pad such as every pixel of the image is convolved the same amount of time ("full").

You could implement your own function to get the shape for all dimension with

```
from keras.utils.conv_utils import conv_output_length

def conv_output_shape(input_shape, kernel_shape, strides, padding, dilate):  
    # assuming only spatial dimensions
    dims = range(len(kernel_shape))
    output_shape = [
        conv_output_length(input_shape[d], kernel_shape[d], padding, strides[d], dilate[d])
        for d in dims
    ]
    output_shape = tuple(
        [0 if input_shape[d] == 0 else output_shape[d] for d in dims]
    )
    return output_shape
```

Comment: PyTorch's solution: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/82559